# Getting a new router broke my internet on my Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns

Today, my internet modem and router was replaced with a new unit. Everything else in my house worked, except for my Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS server. I am able to remote into it, and it can see my local network, but cannot access anything in the internet beyond the router.

Here's an error to go on. When performing `docker-compose pull` I get this error on each attempt for an image pull

```
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Get https://lscr.io/v2/: dial tcp 35.155.221.103:443: connect: no route to host
```

I used to suspect it was DNS, but @steeldriver in the comments pointed out that the server actually does seem to be able to resolve hostnames. Now I suspect it may be a networking config related to the gateway.

Of note, the new router has a new gateway address. It used to be 192.168.1.1 but now it is 192.168.1.254. I tried messing around with cloud-init config files. For some reason, the gateway4 entry in cloud-init was 192.168.1.0 even though that was not the gateway address. I changed it to 192.168.1.254 and restarted the machine. However, now I cannot even remote into the machine any longer. I now think it could be a networking config. Is there any way to do a complete factory reset of cloud-init?

Here is what the cloud init yaml file was. I had to type this in from a screenshot, so forgive any formatting mistakes, but the content is accurate.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.130/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.0
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
  version: 2
```

I've tried changed the gateway4 to 192.168.1.254 and restarted the machine, however upon restart I can no longer remote into the machine. Please advise

Comment: What makes you think it is a DNS issue? Does `lscr.io` resolve to something different than `35.155.221.103` on other machines in your local network?

Comment: I googled the first line of the error and kept getting articles about how fixing a dns problem resolved the issue. That's a good point that lscr.io does resolve to that address. I'm not sure what else would cause such an issue where things can talk to it but it cannot talk to the outside internet.

Comment: So, of note, the new router has a new gateway address. It used to be 192.168.1.1 but now it is 192.168.1.254. I tried messing around with cloud-init config files. For some reason, the gateway4 entry in cloud-init was 192.168.1.0 even though that was not the gateway address. I changed it to 192.168.1.254 and restarted the machine. However, now I cannot even remote into the machine any longer. 

I now think it could be a networking config. Is there any way to do a complete factory reset of cloud-init?

Comment: cloud-init is populated by other configs.  It also in a server instance isnt going to overwrite your configs unless its set to by other tooling or preseed files (which dont exist after a successful server install typically).  Share your servers networking configs please.

Comment: Thomas Ward, thanks for the response. I've updated the question with more info and one of the cloud-init config files

Comment: I've solved the problem! It was definitely networking config. I plan on writing up a details answer and posting later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem!

## Root Cause

I got a new router from my ISP, which came with a different default IP for the gateway. The previous router had a gateway IP of 192.168.1.1 and the new router has a gateway IP of 192.168.1.254. The networking config of the server specified the gateway as 192.168.1.1, which was no longer there. As a result, traffic could not exit through the new router. The rest of my devices in my house worked fine because they used dynamic DHCP allocation, whereas the server did not.

The following solution will only work for you if the root cause is the same!

## Solution

Find your networking config and change the gateway address to your new gateway address. For me, it was in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg`. For others, it may be in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`. The config posted above in the question is a good format, it just needs the correct values. Ensure the interface, addresses, and gateway are all correct.
If that doesn't work, also try running `ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev eno0`. Replace the IP with your gateway IP and the last value with your internet interface.

## Problems Along the Way

I ran into some red herrings along the way, and took a step backwards before getting back to square one and finally solving the problem.

At first, I thought it was dns, so I mucked around with my DNS quite a bit. Until, a commenter here pointed out that it appeared my server *was* resolving hostnames! So I started messing around with cloud-config files. I made a change to cloud-config to just change the gateway, and restarted the machine. I don't remember exactly what commands were run, so I cannot caution against something exactly. However, I do know that after the restart, I could no longer remote into the box. Using a local terminal, I was able to find that the device name in the cloud config file was `enp1s0` while `ip address` revealed that that was not a valid interface. `eno1` was the correct interface, so the cloud config change broke all traffic in and out of the machine. Correcting that allowed me to get back to square one, to remote into the box. That meant I was able to continue to troubleshoot from my comfortable workstation and the machine was able to at least connect to the local network again.

Then, I focused in on a networking problem. Running `ip route` revealed no default route. A default route looks like `default via 192.168.1.254 dev eno1`. I tried a couple restarts with cloud config but nothing worked. As a test to ensure it was cloud-config failing to set a default route, I saw this question
https://serverfault.com/questions/877880/how-can-i-add-a-default-gateway-with-the-ip-command-not-the-route-command
and ran `ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev eno0`. That worked and stuck beyond restarts.